# Now getting error "message="Cannot achieve consistency level ONE" info={'required_replicas': 1, 'alive_replicas': 0, 'consistency': 'ONE'}"

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql, cql3

Cassandra version: dsc-cassandra-2.1.9

Had 3 nodes, one of which was down for a long time. Brought it back up and decomissioned it. Then did a nodetool removenode.

When I try to make a cql query I get the above error.

Initially thought this might be because replication strategy was SimpleStrategy. So did a `ALTER KEYSPACE history WITH REPLICATION =
  {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 2};`

and changed the `endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` instead of `SimpleSnitch`

did a nodetool repair on both nodes and restarted the cassandra services

But the problem is still there. What do I do?

EDIT 1: Nodetool status of machine A

```
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.99.xxx  19.8 GB    256     ?       xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxx4ea  RAC1
UN  192.168.99.xxx  18.79 GB   256     ?       xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx15  RAC1
```

nodetool status output of machine B

```
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.99.xxx  19.8 GB    256     ?       xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx4ea  RAC1
UN  192.168.99.xxx  18.79 GB   256     ?       xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxf15  RAC1
```

Comment: Why did you do a removenode after decommissioning? You should only need to decom.  Also, the output of running nodetool status against both remaining nodes would be helpful.

Comment: Added the status output above. Host Ids match. Did a removenode because after the decommission nodetool status was still showing the decommissioned node

Answer (score 0):

What is weird is that under the columns **Owns** you have no %, only the ?. This same issue occured to me in the past when I bootstrapped a new C* cluster and was using SimpleStrategy and SimpleSnitch. I did like you an ALTER KEYSPACE to switch to NetworkTopology and GossipingPropertyFileSnitch but it did not solve my issue so I rebuilt the cluster from scratch (fortunately I had no data inside)

If you have a backup of your data somewhere, just try to rebuild the 2 nodes from scratch.

Otherwise, consider backing up your sstable files on one node and rebuild the cluster and put the sstables back. Be careful because some file name/folder renaming may be necessary